# What should be the right API structure using CakePHP

Tags: php, api, cakephp

I've been working for a while on an *API-including project*. I have an `ApiUsersController` which handles all user's actions for the API and another API controller.
But I need to ensure that this is secure, so I've created an `apiKey()` function which detects if the user sending the request to my API has the right credentials.

My question now is where should I put the `apiKey()` function in order to make use of it in any API controller?

Any API security recommendations are also very welcomed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found the CakePHP OAuth Plugin very helpful - handles a lot of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> My question now is where should I put the apiKey() function in order
>   to make use of it in any Api controller?

Easy to answer, the correct place is an [authentication adapter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html). Ceeram has already created a token (that's what you're using) adapter for CakePHP. [See this link here](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/Authenticate).

If you want a more secure way you should go for OAuth as suggested by Dave. But instead of using a specific OAuth plugin I would go for [Opauth for CakePHP](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth), it comes with an OAuth Strategy adapter.

Also instead of creating API controllers I would [use prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) and share most of the code for the API actions with the normal actions in a model. This way it can be reused very easy and no need to duplicate work.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful I can say! Thank you! Concerning the prefix routing for the api controllers, i thank that's impossible by the time the api controller has to handle with JSON data and the normal controller with plain input data..so the code is a bit different..but please, you're very welcomed to suggest me a solution to this issue,too :)

Comment: Are you talking about sending json to the server or responding with json? See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: I'm talking about both,I make use of json for requests and for responses,too. (I've seen the link you posted,that's what helped me build my api till now).

Comment: So you send json in a POST request? Why not post directly? Either turn the json body of the POST request into the structure the models expect or send directly the expected data structure using POST.